# Error when inserting into Informix Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, solaris, ssms, informix, linked-server

I am working on an integration between a SQL Server database and an Informix database. The databases are running on separate servers. I have created a Linked Server to Informix using the [Informix OLE DB provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21195578). I am able to retrieve data from Informix no problem. However, when I try to run an insert into Informix, I receive the following error:

```
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Ifxoledbc" for linked server "INFORMIX2" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

I have verified that I can insert into the Informix database from the SQL Server machine, using the ConnectTest application that comes with the Informix Client SDK, so I don't think this is an permissions/firewall issue.

Here is how I am running the insert in my stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DECLARE
@error_msg NVARCHAR(4000),
@error_severity INT,
@error_state INT,
@today datetime,
@set_no int

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

SET @today = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 1)

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY 

--do stuff, including insert into Informix

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

SELECT
@error_msg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
@error_severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
@error_state = ERROR_STATE()

-- Error has occured and transaction is uncommittable
IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
BEGIN
    SET @error_msg = @error_msg + ' The transaction has been rolled back.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

-- Transaction is still committable
IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
BEGIN
    SET @error_msg = @error_msg + ' The transaction was recoverable and was committed.'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END

-- Report the error
RAISERROR (@error_msg, @error_severity, @error_state)

END CATCH
```

I have the Distributed Transaction Coordinator configured, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction). I have also tried setting the communication level to No Authentication Required, but received the same error.

[image]

Is there something that needs to be configured on the Informix server? Like a Distributed Transaction Coordinator equivalent in Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a solution to the transaction issue, I've found the best possible workaround. In SSMS, go to Linked Servers > Providers. Right-click on Ifxoledbc (the Informix OLE DB provider) and select Properties. Check Enable on the properties below.

[image]

The "Allow inprocess" will allow you to insert into Informix. However, **you cannot use a transaction**. You have to use a Try-Catch and then use some old-school methods to ensure that the insert was successful (i.e., count on the target table).