# Error during inserting data into linked server via stored procedure on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a linked server (say Linked_Server_A) on an another SQL server (say B)

From the B, I'm inserting data into A via stored procedure on B.

```
INSERT INTO [Linked_Server_A].[A].[dbo].[Table]
exec B.dbo.sp_procedure
```

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Linked_Server_A" was unable to begin a
>   distributed transaction.

B.dbo.sp_procedure has just select statements from a table kept on B. That's it.

Where am I going wrong ?

**EDIT:**

I see some people are saying this is duplicate of [Unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction) but it's not the case. I'm not explicitly initiating distributed transaction.

Also I'm able to insert records via below query perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO [Linked_Server_A].[A].[dbo].[Table]
select * from B.table1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475790/1080354

Comment: try this https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2015/04/ole-db-provider-sqlncli11-linked-server-unable-distributed-transaction/