# The operation could not be performed & unable to begin a distributed transaction on Entity connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I had issue in entity connection. I have stored procedure which retrieve the data using linked server in the stored procedure. Whenever I connected the stored procedure on entity, I'm getting the below exception when retrieves the data from entity connection. But the results comes in SQL server.

> **Issue :** The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerName" was unable to
>   begin a distributed transaction.

I have tried to apply the settings to enable the distributed transaction and other solution. But it never works. Could you please suggest me any other solution on this?

In SQL server the result retrieved properly. But in entity connection only I'm getting this issue. I have removed the codes from transaction scope and implemented out of the transaction scope. But still it is not resolved.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Arunkumar Murugesan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)

Comment: @Backs: I have already tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction. But it doesn't work.