# Insert return records from stored procedure - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The script below return a select records:

```
EXEC [LINK_SERV].[DB_SAMPLE].[dbo].[SP_SAMPLE] '1235123'
```

The I want to insert the return records to a temp table so I wrote the script below (assumed temp table is already created):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC [LINK_SERV].[DB_SAMPLE].[dbo].[SP_SAMPLE] '1235123'
```

But I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LINK_SERV" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.
>
> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 25
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LINK_SERV" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Please advise the specific config to enable this. I tried the same code in some other server and it work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Maybe a cloned server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)?  Can you get records at all from the procedure?  
Other possibilities are if it's trying to build the temp table on the remote db for some reason, although that's unlikely.

Comment: Yes, when executing the stored procedure alone (first script) returns a records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the beauty of [OPENQUERY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) comes into great use.

i.e. something like this...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable2
SELECT Col1, Col2, etc
FROM dbo.MyTable1
  LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(<<LINKEDSERVER>>,
            'SELECT BLAHBLAH 
             FROM dbo.BLAHBLAH WHERE <something> = <something>);
```

Comment: Coming the this idea, i reconstruct the script to: `INSERT INTO #TempTable (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2 FROM 
OPENQUERY([LINK_SERV],'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC [DB_SAMPLE].[dbo].SP_SAMPLE ''123456''')`