# Trigger from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server

I created trigger in SQL Server for Oracle, if new product is added in SQL Server then it should be automatically added to Oracle Table also using Linked Server. I've tried to insert record using regular query and it works but it doesn't work with trigger. Please help me figure out what's wrong. Here are my queries.

Regular query (It works)

```
 INSERT INTO PRODUCT_IMP..PROD_MASTER.PRODUCT_TBL   --ORACLE
 SELECT  BARCODE,NAME,SUPPLIER,CATEGORY,GETDATE()   --SQL Server
 FROM [dbo].[product_tbl]
```

Trigger (It doesn't work)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Product_INSERT]
   ON [dbo].[product_tbl]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  
   INSERT INTO PRODUCT_IMP..PROD_MASTER.PRODUCT_TBL
   SELECT  BARCODE,NAME,SUPPLIER,CATEGORY,GETDATE()
  FROM
  inserted
END
```

Gives error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PRODUCT_IMP" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.". Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Product_INSERT, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0] The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PROD_MASTER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: "OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PRODUCT_IMP" returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Product_INSERT, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PROD_MASTER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

Comment: Try disabling the "Distributed Transactions for RPC" property of the linked server.

Comment: I Set it to false, still the same error.

Comment: There are more suggestions here. Go through  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction

Comment: I'll go through it. Thank you.